# Bootloader code stm32 controller

Tags: iot, stm32, bootloader, firmware, ota

I am trying to develop the Firmware Over The Air(FOTA) for the STM32(L4-Series) controller as IoT application. I have little bit confused in below topic/section that how it work & goes:

1. How to build the bootloader & load it into controller?
2. how to download the new firmware code(from over the air i.e updated Firmware)?
3. And how to identify the newer and older version's of code?

Comment: the topic is much too broad. If have to ask all those general questions, I think it is too early for you for this task. You will need a bit more experience.

Answer (score -1):

I am writings steps to do so, but it seems you just started this 
Get bootloader code of the controller, you will need it to customize the code.

1. your firmware (old) will download new firmware, copy it into an inactive area and it will set a flag and then it will perform a software reset.
2. After reset, the bootloader will check flag if set it will copy the
   new firmware from the inactive area to active area. So new firmware is
   active now.

The reason why old firmware will download the new firmware is that we want to keep the bootloader code as minimum as possible. So, the application process the new firmware maybe by CRC check. And to upgrade the firmware OTA you need to verify that your new firmware is 100% correct otherwise a single bit error can cause severe problems.

Comment: App should not download anything. Wrong

Comment: I am working on FOTA over a year and found that it is a best practice to process the new firmware by existing firmware. If you have any other suggestion please share the method.

Comment: Hi Muhammad, 
You are right, I am also going as per your suggestion. I am working on the STM32L4 controller with GSM module with it. I have read the application note for the bootloader and system memory boot available from the STM website. I also read the In-Application-Programming(IAP) which codes for the firmware version checking & download and all, also there some setting for the booting memory for loading the new firmware in flash memory.
Sir If you have any sample code for these so please can you share it with me.